# update php version on usbwebserver

Tags: php, mediawiki

I installed an usbwebserver (version 8.7) and a mediawiki on an USB- stick.

When I start usbwebserver it works fine and tells me php Version 5.4.17 is installed.

If I start mediawiki I get the error "required php- Version is at least 5.5.9.

How can I install a newer php on the stick?

I do not know, what information you need to answer my question. It is installed as a windows Version.

Comment: Download old MediaWiki version. check https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Compatibility for PHP version compatibility. It seems MediaWiki v1.26 supports PHP version 5.4.17

Comment: @Sourav Ghosh: Thank you, if there is no other way I will do this. But I still hope, that it is possible to update php

Comment: just replace the php files in the php folder with the newer php version.

Comment: @Tschallacka: which files are needed? both directories are completely different: USBserver: Directory `ext` and 13 files, including `php.exe`, some dlls and some txt- files.  In the downloaded version there are 11 Folders more, lots of files but no dll and no `php.exe`. I can not imagine, that it would work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download the Windows release of PHP 5.6 from [the official site](http://windows.php.net/download/), open the archive and overwrite all matching files on the USB stick with files from the zip. If the folder structure doesn't match, you're probably better off keeping the existing structure on the USB stick since the LAMP setup might be dependent on those specific paths.

Comment: Thank you very much, that I needed. I do not know anything about php and so I needed exactly that hint. Btw: I copied all and it worked.